# accessing root public directory nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to access the root public directory without using `../../../` something like this. The below code works fine, but just thought the way i am accessing my public folder is bit messier.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../../public')   });
});
```

Application structure:

```
/app
--node-modules
--public
   --app //contains all angularjs related files
   --assets //contains images and js libraries
   --index.html
--server
 --routes
   --index.js //this holds all the route related code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On way is to use [app-root-path](https://github.com/inxilpro/node-app-root-path). It is a module that helps you access your application's root path from anywhere in the application without resorting to relative paths.

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, appRoot + '/public')   });
});
```